# Spring Security Oauth2 dynamic redirect uri

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

How do i dynamically specify redirect uri for Oauth2 Authorization code flow in spring security? I have a use case where the application is being accessed by multiple users using 2 to 3 different urls. A user using one particular url has no access to another url. In this case, i want to configure oauth2 so that i can just provide /login or something instead of the entire url

Comment: AFAIK you could only configure a static redirect URL with Spring Security, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2login-advanced However, you do not need different redirect URLs. Instead you should give your user different roles.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to be able to login and use my web app from two different urls, one for running the frontend locally from  `localhost.app.mydomain.com` and one real url like `app.mydomain.com` using Google to login.

**Simple solution**
To achieve this in Spring Security I registered two different `ClientRegistration`'s with the exact same info, except for the `name`, `registrationId` and the `redirectUri`

From the frontend I can then control which Oauth2 client I use by invoking the different `registrationId` endpoints which in turn decides which domain I'm logged into and which redirectUri will be used based on if I'm running my frontend locally or not.

It is not truly dynamic but solves the case where you have a limited number or redirect urls that you know on beforehand which can be controlled from the frontend this way.

**Dynamic solution**
Another more common solution, which I also use in my code, would probably be to pass a `state` parameter with the call to the oauth client in Spring. That will then get passed on to google and be returned untouched to Spring security from the google login flow. This can have whatever info you want to decided by the frontend and then decoded in the backend and e.g. the `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` use this data to `setDefaultTargetUrl` to this which will cause a redirect to wherever the frontend decided on a successful login.